# How can I debug a ptrace tracee?

Tags: gdb, ptrace

I'm writing a program that involves controlling a tracee process with `ptrace`. Of course, there are bugs :) To fix my bugs, I'd like to be able to inspect the tracee's state with `gdb`. However, `gdb -p` says:

```
warning: process X is already traced by process Y
```

If I just use `PTRACE_DETACH`, then the tracee will resume executing until I launch `gdb`, which can destroy the state I'm trying to examine.

Any suggestion for how to examine the runtime state of a ptrace tracee (perhaps with tools other than `gdb`) is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any suggestion for how to examine the runtime state of a ptrace tracee

One way is have the tracer implement GDB [remote debugging protocol](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Protocol.html). Additional documentation [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Stub.html).

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39736752/50617) shows how to detach a process without resuming it.

Comment: Perfect! Detach without resume is just what I am looking for. No wonder you are employed!